# Can't remove spaces from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Have this data:

```
                              region gdp_per_capita
0                      Coasts of USA         71 546
1          USA: New York, New Jersey         81 615
2                    USA: California         74 205
3                   USA: New England         74 000
```

Wanna get this:

```
                              region gdp_per_capita
0                      Coasts of USA          71546
1          USA: New York, New Jersey          81615
2                    USA: California          74205
3                   USA: New England          74000
```

Tried to use `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')`, but it did not work

Comment: `df['gdp_per_capita'] = df['gdp_per_capita'].str.replace(' ', '')`

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns...` just replaces the values in the actual column labels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just this should do:

```
df['gdp_per_capita'] = df['gdp_per_capita'].astype(str).str.replace('\s+', '').replace('nan', np.nan)
df['gdp_per_capita'] = pd.to_numeric(df['gdp_per_capita'])
print(df)

                      region gdp_per_capita
0              Coasts of USA          71546
1  USA: New York, New Jersey          81615
2            USA: California          74205
3           USA: New England          74000
```

Comment: I do not why, but it does not work. While, if I assign the first col df['region'] - it works. Strange..

Comment: Yes - https://rb.gy/dfqpv8 . It is xlsx file, which data was imported from

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to work with numbers rather than strings.

Hence, replacing `' '` with `''` and using `pd.to_numeric` seems like an easy and solid approach.

Let me suggest another one which might or might not be good (it depends on your dataset).

If the thousands in your dataset are separated by a whitespace (`' '`), you can just read your `df` as

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, thousands = ' ')
```

and all your columns with `74 109` would be read as `74109` and `dtype` integer or float.

Comment: Got this : ValueError: Unable to parse string "74 205" at position 2

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
df['gdp_per_capita'] = df['gdp_per_capita'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("[^0-9]", "", str(x))).astype(int)
```

Comment: It would be best to add some explanation around this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure it will work or not but try the following:

1. Trim leading space of column in pandas – lstrip()
2. Trim trailing space of column in pandas – rstrip()
3. Trim Both leading and trailing space of column in pandas – strip()
4. Strip all the white space of column in pandas.

Let me know if it works :)